# Style not applied when is binded by DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm a little confused. Im creating a sample and have a default template for my textbox. What Im trying to archive is to apply style to border and specify BorderBrush inside. When this style is applied this

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type newLibrary:MyTextBox}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
        Value="True" />

<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation"
        Value="None" />
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
        Value="{x:Null}" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth"
        Value="120" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight"
        Value="20" />
<Setter Property="AllowDrop"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type newLibrary:MyTextBox}">
      <Border Name="Border"
              CornerRadius="2"
              Padding="2"
              BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
        </Border.Background>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlLightColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                      x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />

      <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" >
          <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" >
            <Setter.Value>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myconv}">
                <Binding/>
                <Binding/>
              </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </Border.Style>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Unfortunately when Im trying to extract this style (to override it later) it does not work - border does not become red.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type newLibrary:MyTextBox}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
        Value="True" />

<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation"
        Value="None" />
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
        Value="{x:Null}" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth"
        Value="120" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight"
        Value="20" />
<Setter Property="AllowDrop"
        Value="true" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type newLibrary:MyTextBox}">
      <Border Name="Border"
              CornerRadius="2"
              Padding="2"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Style="{DynamicResource VisualStyle}">
        <Border.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
        </Border.Background>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlLightColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                  <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                      x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />


      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: tell us more about the location of your styles both of them? and if you try to put `x:Key="customBorder"` on your main style and then use this `BasedOn="{Static` or `DynamicResource customBorder}"` in your second style. HTH

Comment: they located in themes\generic.xaml. Actually Im trying to replace <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" > ..... with  <Border Name="Border" Style="{DynamicResource VisualStyle}"> but it does not work. Without exctraction it works as expected